# Странности: программа не запускается из меню "Пуск"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-xp, visual-studio-2010

Приветствую. Столкнулся на днях с небольшой проблемой. Я написал программу в `VS2010`, экспортировал экзешник со всеми необходимыми файлами в отдельный каталог, запускаю - работает. После этого в контекстном меню экзешника выбираю пункт "`Pin to start menu`", пробую запустить из меню "Пуск" - программа вылетает при запуске (при этом, судя по ошибке, она ведет себя так, будто не может обнаружить некоторые необходимые файлы в своем рабочем каталоге). При этом, запуск через ярлык (и с раб.стола, и из меню "Пуск"), а также через панель быстрого запуска проходит успешно.

Все вышесказанное относится только к `Windows XP`, на `Windows 7` такой проблемы не возникает.

Чем может быть причиной такого странного поведения?

Comment: Может быть, вы не предусмотрели, что текущий каталог программы может не совпадать с каталогом, где лежат файлы программы?

Comment: Все файлы программы и исполняемый файл лежат в одном каталоге. Что значит "текущий каталог"?

Comment: Действительно, текущий каталог не совпадает с каталогом программы. Как можно "привязать" его к моему каталогу?

Comment: Самый дешёвый метод — в начале программы установить текущий каталог на каталог, где лежит файл с программой. Учтите, это может не сработать, если программа лежит на сетевой шаре (текущий каталог не может на шаре).  
Другой, более правильный метод, как советует @pincher1519 — переписать программу, чтобы она не пользовалась относительными путями.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@maximus](/users/12475/maximus), завязываться на текущий каталог, ИМХО это не правильно. Если нужно искать файлы рядом с исполнительным - так и делайте так. Получите каталог, где расположено приложение запущенное, найдите нужный файл в этом каталоге.
Какой язык программирования используете?

Comment: @pincher1519, спасибо, так и сделал!
Использую C++